# Laravel Nova 4 endless redirect loop after upgrade: Any ideas?

Tags: laravel-nova

New to Laravel, and just inherited a Laravel 7/Nova 3 site. Thanks to Laravel Shift I've updated it to Laravel 10/Nova 4. So far so good; the public site loads.

But when I try to access /nova, I'm redirected to /nova/login endlessly (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). config/nova.php and app/Providers/NovaServiceProviders all look good. Composer update runs cleanly.  Nothing helpful in the laravel log, and nothing in the JS Console (the redirect happens in the Location header of the http response).

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

- Andrew

Tried to access /nova
Expected Nova auth screen at /nova/login
Result: /nova/login keeps redirecting to itself

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm running into the same issue...

Comment: @ploni IIRC, the 'Update Published Stubs' steps worked for me: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/upgrade.html#update-published-stubs

Answer (score 0):

You might have fixed this already, however for others running into the same issue in the future, here's how I fixed it.

I followed the steps in [this section](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/upgrade.html#updating-configuration-assets-and-translations) of the upgrade guide. After this I had to register my newly created dashboard in the `dashboards` array inside of `App/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php`.